# Визуализиция в Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

К примеру есть два разных pandas-датафрейма.

`for dataframe in dataframes:
        print(dataframe[-1:])
        dataframe[-1:].plot(kind='bar')`

Данный код возвращает два разных графика:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно два графика отобразить на одной картинке, чтобы один из них находился слева, а другой справа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался.

Использовал функцию concat и строил график по двум строкам.

`average_df = pd.concat([dataframes[0][-1:],dataframes[1][-1:]])
average_df.plot(kind='bar')`